# Architecture tip on how to deal with Premium accounts, plan duration and renewal

Tags: database, design-patterns, database-design, architecture

I'm creating a website which has a premium user feature. I'm thinking on how to design the database to store the premium user plan, and how to check it..

My main idea so far is:

- Having 2 fields on the user table: `premium` (boolean) and `expires` (date)
- When user does payment, it will calculate the plan duration, set premium to 1, and the expire date to the end of the duration
- Every time I check if `user->isPremium()`, it will also check if it's expired.. if so, set it back to zero and offer a renewal
- Aside from this, all payments /transactions will be recorded in a logs table for record keeping.

This is a simple design I thought, but since this is a common feature on many websites, I thought of asking you guys how do the pros do this?

This probably won't make much difference on the design, but I'll use Stripe for handling payments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks good to me. It is simple and solves your problem.

**Hint 1**: Depending on the semantics of your `premium` and `expires` fields, you do not need both. You can just change your `user->isPremium()` to check if the expires date has passed. Make sure you also change how you handle offering a renew.

**Hint 2**: I am working in a system that handles plan subscriptions and I had to deal with the following cases:

- Permit users renew/extend the subscription before expiration date.
- Different prices for different durations.
- Discounts.
- The delay between bill generation and payment confirmation.
- Users with pending payments trying to buy again.
- Users asking to cancel current subscriptions.

Hope it helps.